# Inserting .txt file as html

Tags: html, iframe, embedding, plaintext

Is there a way to insert a .txt file into a webpage and have the server/browser interpret it as html instead of just displaying the code?

I've tried using iframe as below, but that just displays the code instead of interpreting the code. I know the obvious way to do this would be to save the file as .htm and insert that file; the trouble is, my server doesn't let me upload .htm files.

```
<iframe src="url.txt" type="text" width="100%" style="height:1000px"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. In order to be interpreted by browser, it has to be sent with `Content-Type: text/html` HTTP herader (file extension is irrelevant by itself, but is often used by server to guess `Content-Type`). So if your server does not allow you to upload HTML files, you cannot do this.